# Alternatives to deprecated Files.copy, ByteStreams.copy, InputSupplier

Tags: android, inputstream, guava, deprecated

I'm upgrading Guava library in my application. I have the following structure in several places, to create & write to a `File` from an `InputStream`.

```
File destination;
InputStream myInputStream; 
.
.
.
Files.copy(new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
    @Override
    public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
        return myInputStream;
    }
}, destination);
```

The problem is, `InputSupplier` and `Files.copy` have been deprecated, and some other alternatives like `ByteStreams.copy` are deprecated as well

Can anybody tell me if there's a natural substitute in Guava to write an arbitrary InputStream to a File?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning `myInputStream` from `openStream` is extremely dangerous and is not how `ByteSource` is intended to be used.  `ByteSource.openStream()` should open a *new* `InputStream`.

Instead, you should use `Files.asByteSink(destination).writeFrom(myInputStream)`, or you should move the creation of `myInputStream` to the `openStream()` implementation.

Comment: As to _why_ it's dangerous: the problem is relying on it to _close_ your `InputStream`. The same code that _opens_ a stream generally should also ensure that the stream is closed, typically by using try-finally (or ideally, with Java 7, try-with-resources). A `ByteSource` that opens the stream in `openStream()` will handle both opening and closing the stream for you. If it isn't opening the stream itself, some other code should really be responsible for closing the stream, as there's likely a possibility of failing to close the stream in some situations otherwise.

Comment: wow, good to know all this, thanks for the in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://javadox.com/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/com/google/common/io/Files.html#copy(com.google.common.io.InputSupplier,%20java.io.File))
 suggests to replace `File.copy` with `from.copyTo(Files.asByteSink(destination))` where `from` must be a `ByteSource` instead of an `InputSupplier`.

So your code must be changed in the following way:

```
new ByteSource() {
    @Override
    public InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
        return myInputStream;
    }
}.copyTo(Files.asByteSink(destination));
```